# How to display only YEAR by Solr

Tags: solr

How to return the year from a full date in Solr

```
2019-12-20 14:05:38.327 -> 2019
```

Comment: That's usually the task of your frontend and not Solr. If you only want year in a field (for faceting for example) index a separate field with just the year (if you also need the full timestamp)..

Comment: I understand but is there any chance to return only the year from the date?

Comment: I'm not aware of any easy way to achieve that, no.